# Get folders and files recursively from a folder in alphabetical order in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I need to get all the folders and files from a folder recursively in alphabetical order (folders first, files after)

Is there an implemented PHP function which caters for this?

I have this function:

```
function dir_tree($dir) {
   $path = '';
   $stack[] = $dir;
   while ($stack) {
       $thisdir = array_pop($stack);
       if ($dircont = scandir($thisdir)) {
           $i=0;
           while (isset($dircont[$i])) {
               if ($dircont[$i] !== '.' && $dircont[$i] !== '..' && $dircont[$i] !== '.svn') {
                   $current_file = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                   if (is_file($current_file)) {
                       $path[] = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                   } elseif (is_dir($current_file)) {
                        $path[] = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                       $stack[] = $current_file;
                   }
               }
               $i++;
           }
       }
   }
   return $path;
}
```

I have sorted the array and printed it like so:

```
$filesArray = dir_tree("myDir");
natsort($filesArray);

foreach ($filesArray as $file) {
    echo "$file<br/>";
}
```

What I need is to know when a new sub directory is found, so I can add some spaces to print it in a directory like structure instead of just a list.

Any help?

Many thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a link which helped me a lot in what I was trying to achieve:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1917

This might help someone else, it creates a list with folders first, files after. When you click on a subfolder, it submits and another page with the folders and files in the partent folder is generated.

Comment: Code snippet now missing.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

```
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
foreach($directory_iterator as $filename => $path_object)
{
    echo $filename;
}
```

I'm not sure though if it returns the files in alphabetical order.

**Edit:**

As you say it does not, I think the only way is to sort them yourself.

I would loop through each directory and put directories and files in a seperate arrays, and then sort them, and then recurse in the directories.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not :)

Comment: I guess you would have to create something yourself then.

Comment: Like Ikke says, just drop into an array and sort it.

Comment: You don't need to sort each subarray. Just drop it into an array and `asort($dirs)` at the end. Simples.